# File extension .pdf automatically added to link

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf

Here's a minimal example:

```
% File: test.tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

(1) Rendered as link (red). Normal behaviour.

\href{abc.html}{abc}

(2) Rendered as citation (cyan). File extension .pdf appended.

\href{abc}{abc}

\end{document}
```

After running pdfLaTeX on this minimal example, the link in (2) is rendered as a citation with a `.pdf` extension appended.  Mousing over it shows 'Go to file "doc.pdf"' (when viewed with evince).

How can I get it rendered as a link and also get rid of the added `.pdf` extension?

I'm using TeXLive 2013 and pdfTeX version is 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Are you trying to link a file without extension?

Comment: Yes, a typical case is to link to a README file in the same directory as the pdf document.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting information! I am a user of markdown myself but was *overwhelmed* when SX presented me with a html editor text area. :-) Maybe it should point people to the formatting information.

Answer (score 6):

`hyperref` interprets `\href{abc}{...}` as file link with an extension, that can be configured by option `extension`. If the protocol is specified, then the result is a URL link:

```
\href{http:abc}{...}
```

Comment: `\href{http:abc}{...}` points to `http:abc` but not `abc`. `\href{file://abc}{abc}` won't work either. Setting extension={} gives a link to `abc.` but not `abc`. :-(